# Is there a podman API which can be used for doing podman login to a private registry?

Tags: networking, containers, podman

I have an existing application deployed in podman. I want to do a podman login into a private registry from inside the container so that i will be able to pull/push images into the private registry. I'm trying to find a podman api for it but didn't fumble upon one till now.

I'm trying it in podman version 4.2.0 in rhel 9.1.

I'm not able to find the api in the [link](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/_static/api.html#tag/images/operation/ImagePullLibpod) also.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to run `podman pull` and `podman push` with user credentials? That's covered on the docs page: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-pull.1.html

Comment: Yes but with podman api not the regular podman pull commands.

Comment: The API page seems to show details for "reference" and "X-Registry-Auth" but I'm afraid I've never used the API directly. Maybe one of the chat channels would be better for you to get help with this?